# How does one go about converting custom post type to post format?

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, post-formats

I have a blog which uses custom post type 'aside' for aside posts. Now that wordpress has custom post formats, I want to use the 'aside' post format instead. Is there a way to convert post typess to post formats?

I'm looking for code/tool similar to wordpress's in-built tool which lets one convert from categories to tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of plugins available that will allow you to do this.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-type-convertr/ or 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/ should get the job done for you.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/convert-post-types/. It did work. However I had to manually create 302 links for all the posts that were converted and that was quite a bit of pain.